# What are the benefits of joining a guild?

Tags: black-desert-online

I see various guilds advertising in the channel chat. Some of them mention having guild benefits. I'm not too interested at the moment in joining a guild for the community aspect, but if there was some in-game benefit of being in a guild I would like to take advantage of that.

Are there any perks available when you join a guild?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](http://forum.blackdesertonline.com/index.php?/topic/7478-guild-system-breakdown-how-it-works/) thread on the Official Forum of this game:

> Salary can also be adjusted by the guild leader depending on the members contribution to the guild.

---

> 1. Kill quests
> 2. Gathering quests
> 3. Crafting quests
> 4. Trading quests

---

> There are passive skills which are applied immediately after the guild leader has put points into them, and there are also active skills which require an item called “Blood Oath”. The item can be bought in the guild store and can only be used by the guild leader. All members will receive the buff as soon as points are put into the skill.

---

> PVP & wars

Comment: Yeap i can confirm :D probably the main reason to join a guild is the Salary you get every day ( depends on guild and your aktivity how much it is) and if you're a soild member and you have access to the guild bank Crafting (endgame contntent) gets easyer. The Quests have no real benefit for you and are more to help your guild.

Comment: I only looked up the answer because this had no answers, feel free to post your own answer or edit mine if you can word it better in function of the game =)

Comment: Nope your Answer is perfektly fine :D